# What is best practice for add total "views" of itemview of Recyclerview?

Tags: java, android

[enter image description here][1]In every social media i seen the TextView called as "views".

So "views" means actually whats thing and when its counted +1(add) ?

Case 1: Whenever users swipe the recyclerview and whatever itemview comes within screen area then itemview "views" counted +1.

Case 2: Whenever users click on the itemview  than itemview "views" counted +1.(I knew about this case that how to implements this)

I thought there could be one of these two. If Case 1 is best than please tell how to start with in onBindViewHolder or any other case than please suggest

https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPRU5.png
I added take an example from fb.
total "views" . 
Is it total no of click on this post ?

Comment: Please clarify your question. It's impossible to understand what you're trying to convey in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Views from Facebook are a completely different thing than `View`'s which are used in Android.

In Android, `View` is a basic element in Android, which is then extended by other classes to add some properties of their own to that `View`.

So, for example,

```
class TextView extends View{}
```

that is  basic question of **Inheritance in OOP.**

Inheritance means, consider an example, you create a base class called "Car", in which you write the code for a basic car, like "Car has four tyres", and all the basic properties that a car has. You then create another class, called Bus, and make it extend this Car class, so that bus will have properties of its parent class "Car", as well as will be able to add some properties of itself, like "Bus is long". So here, class "Car" is like "View", whereas, class "Bus" is like TextView.

So, for example, `TextView` extends the functionality of `View` class to be able to show some text/String inside it. `TextView` is called a `View`, because it inherits the properties of the basic `View` class, and adds some of its own.

**If you're asking** how to implement the "total views" on a post functionality like Facebook, you'll have to add code which will be executed every time `onBindViewHolder` is called in a `RecyclerView`.

So, in `onBindViewHolder`, you'll call the function to get the current view count, and then increment that value and add it in your database on that post.

You have given two cases,

**Edit:**

As asked by you in the comment, you want to:

1. Whenever user sees the post, increment the views in the database.

   For that, you need to call a function like `private void incrementTotalViews();` inside the `onBindViewHolder` of your `RecyclerView.Adapter`, this function should get the latest views, increment it by 1, and then set the new number to the database. Although, this'll be called again and again even if user goes down and comes back up again the post.
2. You want to store value in total visitors when the layout is clicked.
   For that, you need to call a function inside your `ViewHolder`, which will be called whenever the itemView is clicked.

So you need to add something like,

```
itemView.setOnClickListener()
```

below the `super(itemView)` inside your ViewHolder constructor. And in the onClick of this listener, you need to call a function which will store value in total visitors.